# How user mysql IN query like AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns user_id, skills_id. A user have multiple skills with new row. I have to find those users who have same skills_id.

```
user_id skills_id
      1         6
     10         5
     11         2
     11         3
     15         2
     15         4
     15         3
     17         2
     18         2
     18         3
     18         4
     20         2 <-- I have to find users who have values of both 2 and 4 for skill_id. 
     20         4 <-- So user 15 in this example.
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need users with exact same skills or just have a skill in common?

Answer (score 1):

Try this untested query:

```
Select user_id from `table` where skills_id in (2,4) group by user_id having count(*) =2
```

Comment: Untested? I don't believe you ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry believe it or not. But it is so.

Comment: I might suggest a slight adjustment from `having count(*) =2` to `having count(distinct skills_id) =2`, then if they happen to have two `skills_id = 2` it would be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find other users with the same skills.  Assuming the skills are not duplicated, here is one approach:

```
select t.user_id
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.skills_id = t2.skills_id and
        t2.user_id = 20
group by t.user_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from table t3 where t3.user_id = 20);
```

Note that this will return user 20 as well as user 15.  You can filter that out if you like.

If the skills can be duplicated for a user, you would just use `count(distinct)` instead.